# MMLS (Sleuth Kit) not working in some situations

Tags: forensics, backup, disk-image

I am experiencing some issues when using `mmls` command after having created an image with `dcfldd`/`guymager` in some particular situations. Usually this approach seems to be working fine to create physical images of devices, but with some USBs (working fine and undamaged) I manage to create the .dd disk image file, but then it won't be opened by `mmls`, nor `fsstat`.
`fls` does open the file system structure, but it seems like it won't show me any unallocated files just as if this was a logical image.
This is the command run to create a disk image using `dcfldd`:

```
sudo dcfldd  if=/dev/sda hash=sha256 hashlog=usb.sha256hash of=./usb.dd bs=512 conv=noerror,sync,notrunc
```

Also, this is the output of usb.info, generated by `guymager`:

```
GUYMAGER ACQUISITION INFO FILE
==============================

Guymager
========

Version            : 0.8.13-1                                                                                         
Version timestamp  : 2022-05-11-00.00.00 UTC                                                                          
Compiled with      : gcc 12.1.1 20220507 (Red Hat 12.1.1-1)                                                           
libewf version     : 20140812 (not used as Guymager is configured to use its own EWF module)                          
libguytools version: 2.0.2                                                                                            
Host name          : lucafedora                                                                                       
Domain name        : (none)                                                                                           
System             : Linux lucafedora 6.1.7-100.fc36.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jan 18 18:37:43 UTC 2023 x86_64


Device information
==================
Command executed: bash -c "search="`basename /dev/sda`: H..t P.......d A..a de.....d" && dmesg | grep -A3 "$search" || echo "No kernel HPA messages for /dev/sda""
Information returned:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   No kernel HPA messages for /dev/sda

Command executed: bash -c "smartctl -s on /dev/sda ; smartctl -a /dev/sda"
Information returned:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   /usr/bin/bash: line 1: smartctl: command not found
   /usr/bin/bash: line 1: smartctl: command not found

Command executed: bash -c "hdparm -I /dev/sda"
Information returned:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   /usr/bin/bash: line 1: hdparm: command not found

Command executed: bash -c "CIDFILE=/sys/block/$(basename /dev/sda)/device/cid; echo -n "CID: " ; if [ -e $CIDFILE ] ; then cat $CIDFILE  ; else echo "not available" ; fi "
Information returned:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   CID: not available

Hidden areas: unknown


Acquisition
===========

Linux device            : /dev/sda                                        
Device size             : 8053063680 (8.1GB)                              
Format                  : Linux dd raw image - file extension is .dd      
Image path and file name: /home/HOMEDIR/case_usb/usb.dd  
Info  path and file name: /home/HOMEDIR/case_usb/usb.info
Hash calculation        : SHA-256                                         
Source verification     : on                                              
Image verification      : on                                              

No bad sectors encountered during acquisition.
No bad sectors encountered during verification.
State: Finished successfully

MD5 hash                   : --                                                              
MD5 hash verified source   : --                                                              
MD5 hash verified image    : --                                                              
SHA1 hash                  : --                                                              
SHA1 hash verified source  : --                                                              
SHA1 hash verified image   : --                                                              
SHA256 hash                : 7285a8b0a2b472a8f120c4ca4308a94a3aaa3e308a1dd86e3670041b07c27e76
SHA256 hash verified source: 7285a8b0a2b472a8f120c4ca4308a94a3aaa3e308a1dd86e3670041b07c27e76
SHA256 hash verified image : 7285a8b0a2b472a8f120c4ca4308a94a3aaa3e308a1dd86e3670041b07c27e76
Source verification OK. The device delivered the same data during acquisition and verification.
Image verification OK. The image contains exactely the data that was written.

Acquisition started : 2023-01-28 12:27:07 (ISO format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)   
Verification started: 2023-01-28 12:30:11                                    
Ended               : 2023-01-28 12:35:24 (0 hours, 8 minutes and 16 seconds)
Acquisition speed   : 41.97 MByte/s (0 hours, 3 minutes and 3 seconds)       
Verification speed  : 24.62 MByte/s (0 hours, 5 minutes and 12 seconds)      


Generated image files and their MD5 hashes
==========================================

No MD5 hashes available (configuration parameter CalcImageFileMD5 is off)
MD5                               Image file
n/a                               usb.dd
```

Worth to mention that when `mmls` is run against usb.dd it produces **no output** whatsoever. I have to forcefully add `-v` option for it to spit out this kind of information:

```
tsk_img_open: Type: 0   NumImg: 1  Img1: usb.dd
aff_open: Error determining type of file: usb.dd
aff_open: Success
Error opening vmdk file
Error checking file signature for vhd file
tsk_img_findFiles: usb.dd found
tsk_img_findFiles: 1 total segments found
raw_open: segment: 0  size: 8053063680  max offset: 8053063680  path: usb.dd
dos_load_prim: Table Sector: 0
raw_read: byte offset: 0 len: 65536
raw_read: found in image 0 relative offset: 0 len: 65536
raw_read_segment: opening file into slot 0: usb.dd
dos_load_prim_table: Testing FAT/NTFS conditions
dos_load_prim_table: MSDOS OEM name exists
bsd_load_table: Table Sector: 1
gpt_load_table: Sector: 1
gpt_open: Trying other sector sizes
gpt_open: Trying sector size: 512
gpt_load_table: Sector: 1
gpt_open: Trying sector size: 1024
gpt_load_table: Sector: 1
gpt_open: Trying sector size: 2048
gpt_load_table: Sector: 1
gpt_open: Trying sector size: 4096
gpt_load_table: Sector: 1
gpt_open: Trying sector size: 8192
gpt_load_table: Sector: 1
gpt_open: Trying secondary table
gpt_load_table: Sector: 15728639
raw_read: byte offset: 8053063168 len: 512
raw_read: found in image 0 relative offset: 8053063168 len: 512
gpt_open: Trying secondary table sector size: 512
gpt_load_table: Sector: 15728639
gpt_open: Trying secondary table sector size: 1024
gpt_load_table: Sector: 7864319
raw_read: byte offset: 8053062656 len: 1024
raw_read: found in image 0 relative offset: 8053062656 len: 1024
gpt_open: Trying secondary table sector size: 2048
gpt_load_table: Sector: 3932159
raw_read: byte offset: 8053061632 len: 2048
raw_read: found in image 0 relative offset: 8053061632 len: 2048
gpt_open: Trying secondary table sector size: 4096
gpt_load_table: Sector: 1966079
raw_read: byte offset: 8053059584 len: 4096
raw_read: found in image 0 relative offset: 8053059584 len: 4096
gpt_open: Trying secondary table sector size: 8192
gpt_load_table: Sector: 983039
raw_read: byte offset: 8053055488 len: 8192
raw_read: found in image 0 relative offset: 8053055488 len: 8192
sun_load_table: Trying sector: 0
sun_load_table: Trying sector: 1
mac_load_table: Sector: 1
mac_load: Missing initial magic value
mac_open: Trying 4096-byte sector size instead of 512-byte
mac_load_table: Sector: 1
mac_load: Missing initial magic value
```